# Asp.Net - Can a LinkButton.CommandArgument be typed?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, command

Okay so given a `LinkButton` inside a the `ItemTemplate` of a `Repeater` declared like this -

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="restrictionDelete" runat="server" CssClass="restrictionDelete" Text="Delete..."
                OnCommand="lnkDeleteRestriction_Command" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Now,..the repeater is being bound to a list of `Restriction` objects so when the `lnkDeleteRestriction_Command` is fired I'm expecting that I can cast the `CommandEventArgs.CommandArgument` which is an `object` to my `Restriction` type.  This doesn't seem to be so,..I just get the fully qualified type name as a string.

Can I receive a typed command argument at all and if not, why is it an object?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Doh,..I got it.  Although the CommandEventArgs.CommandArgument is an object, LinkButton.CommandArgument is a string!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and it was probably calling ToString to get it to the string, storing the incorrect value.

Comment: Makes you wonder why the EventArgs property is an object though.

Comment: Makes no odds unless you set the property yourself from code, which is pointless!  If you bind it declaratively then it WILL be a string.